# How to calculate the XOR of two bytes in Python?

Tags: python, xor

I used this function to apply the XOR operation between two bytes

```
 def byte_xor(ba1, ba2):
        """ XOR two byte strings """
        return bytes([_a ^ _b for _a, _b in zip(ba1, ba2)])
```

I used the function of two bytes R and L

```
new_R = byte_xor(str(R).encode(), str(self.hash1(str(L).encode())).encode())
```

1. where `str(R).encode()` is equal to `b'X: 0x92405a2937fba74a036c002e51dc8405850afe40123b23f2\nY: 0x2b8471aac0e9b2038dd369d376481585bbf0286927d7607e\n(On curve <P192>)'`
2. `str(self.hash1(str(L).encode())).encode()` is equal to `b'4775954696306753387525785228259522227266813277010037244898'`
3. and `new_R` is equal to `b'l\r\x17\x05A\x0c\x06\x02\t\x03R\x02\x0f\x04\x02UQY\x00\x01S\x05\x04\x0eV\x02\x02\nW\x00\x08QQ\n\x06\x02\x02\n\x03\x06YWV\x06\x07\x06\x02\x02R\x02\x00Q\x00>m\x02\x19\x08'`

What I don't understand is that when I wanted to get the value of R it didn't give me the entire value, somehow it seems that it gave me half of the actual value:

```
R = byte_xor(new_R, str(self.hash1(str(L).encode())).encode())
print('This is R:',R)
This is R: b'X: 0x92405a2937fba74a036c002e51dc8405850afe40123b23f2\nY: 0'
```

Am I doing something wrong? please help me

Comment: ``zip`` does not do padding when one argument is shorter than the other, but stops as soon as one is exhausted. Since the first element is much longer than the second, the result is truncated to the length of the second. Why do you assume that ``R`` can be reconstructed from ``new_R``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to cycle bytes of the second parameter to cover all of the first parameter's content. `zip()` will only match the common length:

```
from itertools import cycle

def byte_xor(ba1, ba2):
        """ XOR two byte strings """
        return bytes([_a ^ _b for _a, _b in zip(ba1, cycle(ba2))])

R = b'X: 0x92405a2937fba74a036c002e51dc8405850afe40123b23f2\nY: 0x2b8471aac0e9b2038dd369d376481585bbf0286927d7607e\n(On curve <P192>)'
H = b'4775954696306753387525785228259522227266813277010037244898'

N = byte_xor(R,H)
print(N)
b'l\r\x17\x05A\x0c\x06\x02\t\x03R\x02\x0f\x04\x02UQY\x00\x01S\x05\x04\x0eV\x02\x02\nW\x00\x08QQ\n\x06\x02\x02\n\x03\x06YWV\x06\x07\x06\x02\x02R\x02\x00Q\x00>m\x02\x19\x08L\x05U\r\r\x02\x05WXU\x03U\x0fU\x07\x03\x00\x00SQ\x01\x03\x0e\\\x06\x05\x04\x0c\n\x04\x0c\r\x07PPT\x07\x00\x0e\x00\x01\x03\x04V\x00\x01\x00\x06U:\x1bx\\\x14WMKNQ\x17\x0be\x08\x0c\x06\x08\x10'
```